python - ImportError: cannot import name '_is_imported_module' from 'dill._dill'
Installed datasets package into python virtual environment. When I try to import it, running,
from datasets import load_dataset, I get this error, "ImportError: cannot import name '_is_imported_module' from 'dill._dill'", then this error, "AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute '_dill'" as I scroll down.
For the full error message:
"\[autoreload of dill.session failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions\\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions\\autoreload.py", line 475, in superreload
module = reload(module)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\importlib\__init_\_.py", line 131, in reload
\_bootstrap.\_exec(spec, module)
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 866, in \_exec
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 995, in exec_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 488, in \_call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\dill\\session.py", line 24, in \<module\>
from .\_dill import (
ImportError: cannot import name '\_is_imported_module' from 'dill.\_dill' (C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\dill_dill.py)
\]
\[autoreload of dill.\_shims failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions\\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions\\autoreload.py", line 500, in superreload
update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions\\autoreload.py", line 397, in update_generic
update(a, b)
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions\\autoreload.py", line 365, in update_class
update_instances(old, new)
File "C:\\Users\\joshu\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions\\autoreload.py", line 323, in update_instances
object.__setattr__(ref, "__class__", new)
TypeError: __class__ assignment: '\_CallableReduce' object layout differs from '\_CallableReduce'
\]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\spyder_kernels\\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\\users\\joshu.spyder-py3\\temp.py:14
from datasets import load_dataset

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\__init_\_.py:18
from .arrow_dataset import Dataset

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\arrow_dataset.py:68
from .arrow_writer import ArrowWriter, OptimizedTypedSequence

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\arrow_writer.py:29
from .features import Features, Image, Value

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\features\__init_\_.py:17
from .audio import Audio

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\features\\audio.py:11
from ..download.streaming_download_manager import xopen, xsplitext

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\download\__init_\_.py:9
from .download_manager import DownloadManager, DownloadMode

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\download\\download_manager.py:43
from ..utils.py_utils import NestedDataStructure, map_nested, size_str

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\utils\\py_utils.py:44
from .\_dill import (  # noqa: F401 # imported for backward compatibility. TODO: remove in 3.0.0

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\utils_dill.py:27
class Pickler(dill.Pickler):

File \~\\anaconda3\\envs\\sentence_similarity\\Lib\\site-packages\\datasets\\utils_dill.py:28 in Pickler
dispatch = dill.\_dill.MetaCatchingDict(dill.Pickler.dispatch.copy())

AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute '\_dill'"

Tried reinstalling and installing an earlier version of dill. That did not work. In addition, I have a jupyter notebook running the same version of datasets, and dill and I didn't run into any issues there.

It looks like to me, at first glance, that dill is trying to import the _dill module, and whatever version of dill is installed is too old to have the _dill module.  If you are using an old version of dill, you might just need to update it.

FYI, I'm the dill author.  It'd be good to report the versions of Python, dill, datasets, etc you are using.  This may also better handled as a Github issue.
